# Javascript - Appending highest index of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using a third party API to populate a card that I have with my website.  This API provides data from the month before. I am expecting this API to be updated with up to date data on a monthly basis. When updated I am expecting it to create a new index in my Array returning from this API.

At the moment I am appending my card with assigning it a specific index. I'm attempting to handle this dynamically without having to change the index I am specifying every month when the API is updated. Based on my research I am unable to find an example of what I trying to accomplish.

I know there's a method `.pop()` to remove the last index of an array but is there a method I can use in order to get the last method of an array and append it?

This is my code at the moment with choosing a specific array

```
$("#dataCard").html(data[3][20]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.push` to add to the end of an array

```
Arr.push(12)//can be whatever
```

Answer (score 0):

**Basic example.**

```
let data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];
let dataInnerLength = data.length - 1;
let lastElem = data[dataInnerLength][data[dataInnerLength].length - 1];

console.log(lastElem); //9
$("#dataCard").html(lastElem);
```

Or using last()

```
let data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];
let lastElem = last(data[data.length - 1]);
console.log(lastElem); //9
```